# Apache POI 4 - Create LINE chart with multi empty cells

Tags: java, apache-poi

I do like to create a line chart base on my data-source but unfortunately, when the line chart y-series across multiple cells it hit NullPointException while plot chat.

I found the error occurred while the column were blank and force to set "0" to make it work.

Anyway, I could plot chart on the empty cells without hard-coded "0"?

Below is the way how i hard-coded the default value,

```
for (int i = 0; headers.size() > i; i++) {
    row.createCell(i, CellType.NUMERIC);
}
```

Below is LineChart code:

```
int rows = numberOfRows - 1;
int cols = headers.size();

XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);
XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
chart.displayBlanksAs(DisplayBlanks.GAP);

XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

// Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
bottomAxis.setOrientation(AxisOrientation.MAX_MIN);
bottomAxis.setTitle("Date");

XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
rightAxis.setTitle("Rates");
rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

XDDFChartLegend chartLegend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
chartLegend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
chartLegend.setOverlay(false);

XDDFLineChartData lineChartData = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
lineChartData.setVaryColors(false);

XDDFDataSource<String> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, rows, 1, 1));

for (int col = 2; cols > col; col++) {
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, rows, col, col));
    XDDFLineChartData.Series series = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) lineChartData.addSeries(xs, ys);
    series.setTitle(headers.get(col), null);
    series.setSmooth(false);
    series.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.NONE);
}

chart.plot(lineChartData);
```

Comment: Maybe substitute the hard coded `0` with a hard coded `"#N/V"`, which tells the diagram not to consider those cells.

Comment: @deHaar just try, not work... it display to excel and fail to plot chart... :(

Comment: Too bad, was worth a try...

Comment: I can confirm empty chart data cells to be a problem up to `apache poi 4.1.0` (`NPE at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChart.fillSheet`). But it is resolved in `apache poi 4.1.1`.

Comment: @AxelRichter your comment are save me from the troublesome set the default value to force plot chart! thanks so much!!!